# specific business POI types in google maps

Tags: google-maps

I've been looking around the net for a while now, but without success.
I'm trying to only show hotels on google maps (API v3) but the only thing I could find, is to turn all business POI off.

```js
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
styles:
[
    {
        featureType: "poi.business",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers:
        [
            {
                visibility: "off"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So I am wondering, is there a way to "filter" out specific business types such as hotels, restaurants, etc and is there a way to view a list of these types as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The places search could be an option as shown in [this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search?hl=de).

The search type there is "store" but as to the [list of available places types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/supported_types) you could use "lodging" as keyword or as to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/google-places-api/browse_thread/thread/0f7cea5416d15e58?pli=1) also "hotel" (with limitations).

[This example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/localsearch/places.html) shows a way to create a list of filtered results.

Comment: I think this is what I am searching for. I'm going to try and work with this. Thanks!